# How get error traces in testers remote devices in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have distributed my app to testers through diawi link. In distribution method in Xcode I select:

> Development: Distribute to members of your team.

When the application has errors I do not know how I can see the error traces.

[I go to iTunes connect and in the error column the testers that have had errors do not show errors.](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev391c4e1e9) and no session counter.

I have waited more than a day to see if errors appear in console.

How can I see the logs when the app crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of 3rd party tools which provide crash analytics, I preferably use friebase Firebase Crashlytics. 
All you have to do is just add the sdk and few lines of code and you are done. You will start receiving the crash reports and analytics and other information like 
Device model,IOS version etc. 
Here is the link : 
[Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwl7nYBRCwARIsAL7O7dFs_AggJ3F6LocBxToaYG7ylJp7Sa3bqZAVzgsUfQ8O1DCN0LuZpLMaAkZQEALw_wcB)